# Unable to use "Letters" from "CKeditor"

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm trying to use [Letters](https://docs.ckeditor.com/letters/latest/guides/overview.html) as the main collaborative text editor for one of our projects. But, I'm unable to run even a simple demo.

This is my "index.html" test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="letters.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function load() {
                Letters.create( document.body, {
                    cloudServices: {
                        tokenUrl: '<Development token URL from https://dashboard.ckeditor.com>',
                        uploadUrl: '<Upload URL from https://dashboard.ckeditor.com>',
                        documentId: 'cats'
                    },
                    title: 'Cats',
                    body: `<p>Cats are awesome.</p>`
                } )
                .then( letters => {
                    console.log( letters.getTitle() );
                    console.log( letters.getBody() );
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
    </body>
</html>
```

There's also a "letters.js" file, but I couldn't even find a download link for Letters. I had to look at the demo page source to find it. If anyone knows an official link, please tell me.

When I open this file (locally or within a web server), nothing happens. The console shows this messages:

```
Logging on browser console. See `cloudServices._logUrl` configuration. Object { message: "letters-restarteditor: Restart.", level: "error", stackTrace: "value@file:///home/(...)/letters.js:1:1018463\n", data: {...} } letters.js:1:47910
Logging on browser console. See `cloudServices._logUrl` configuration. Object { message: "letters-restarteditor: Restart.", level: "error", stackTrace: "value@file:///home/(...)/letters.js:1:1018463\n", data: {...} } letters.js:1:47910
Logging on browser console. See `cloudServices._logUrl` configuration. Object { message: "letters-restarteditor: Switched to offline mode. Too many restarts.", level: "error", stackTrace: "value@file:///home/(...)/letters.js:1:1018463\n", data: {...} } letters.js:1:47910
```

**Does anyone knows what can be happening? Is "Letters" a stable and reliable tool to use in a big project? Being built over CKEditor5, is CKEditor5 a stable and reliable tool? Or I should better stick with CKEditor4?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

<s>There has been no official release of Letters so far, that's why tere is no download link for it. The documentation was published for people who are trying Letters in a private beta program.</s>

<s>I have a good news though, next week there will be a free trial officially available with valid download links, updated documentation, which should work just fine. Within the next few days after offering the trial we will also document on how to customize Letters, add/remove plugins and so on.</s>

As of the end of April 2018, you can sign up to Letters and try it out. For the quick start guide check  https://docs.ckeditor.com/letters/latest/guides/integration/quick-start.html